# Slideshow auto playing blank in then end in Shopify narrative theme

Tags: javascript, slider, shopify, slideshow, shopify-template

I wanted autoplay slideshow in narrative theme its work very well although at the end of the autoplay slideshow, it hangs on a blank slide for quite a bit of time before restarting. how can i remove that and make it slide right to the first image instead of displaying blank . Any help would be great. I entered this code into custom.js

```js
var sections = window.theme.sections;
var slideshowAutoExtension = {
  init: function() {
    this.on('slideshow_desktop_init_done', this._autoplaySlideshow.bind(this));
  },
  _autoplaySlideshow: setInterval(function() {
    var $slide = $('.slideshow__slide--active')
                   .removeClass('slideshow__slide--active');

    var $button = $('.slideshow__button--active')
                   .removeClass('slideshow__button--active');

    var $slides = $('.slideshow__slide');

    var currentIndex = ($slides.index($slide) + 1) % $slides.length;

    $slides
      .eq(currentIndex)
      .addClass('slideshow__slide--active');

    var $buttons = $('.slideshow__button')
      .eq(currentIndex)
      .addClass('slideshow__button--active');

  }, 5000)

};
```

'''

Comment: used the same code you mentioned, didn't  came across such issue providing the recording for the same - https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/3861998?key=b1d0ec08a73ed4b2ef3b0ecd3fba8b93 its working perfectly fine for me

Comment: @JyotiAhluwalia thanks mate works like a charm.